# I am having a hard time to open a MainPage.xaml file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Hi I am beginner in C# and I am learning it from the book " MICROSOFT VISUSL C# STEP BY STEP ". And I am trying to practice exercise to make my first GUI app(VISUAL STUDIO 2015) from the text book. I did everything step by step according to book but when i double click the MainPage.xaml file ,It don' view the layout of UI like it shows in book. I just don't understand why it dose not show the design view window. And I also did right click on .XAML file to click view designer still nothing work. please help me with this situation.

Comment: Post the code you have and we can help you debug it.

Comment: I think OP is asking how to open the designer, which is a Visual Studio question rather than a C# question. `To open the XAML Designer, right-click a XAML file in Solution Explorer and choose View Designer.` - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921077.aspx)

Comment: I did right click on  a XAML file in solution explorer and click on view designer but it just show me the Code that's all..It don't show me the layout..

Comment: Are you sure you are opening a project? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project

Comment: I am practicing exercise and I am not getting the same result as shown in the book. In the book it has shown the layout when you double click the MainPage.XAML file but it don't happen same way  with me.........LibertyLocked

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the way the XAML editor opens in the Visual Studio options. Myself and many WPF developers configure it so it can go directly into XML mode, because it is faster and, frankly, the designer sucks.

Check Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous for earlier than VS2015 and Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> Default Document View for VS2015.

Comment: I did all that you show me here but still nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking at the "XAML" view, but you want the "Design" view. Look for 2 tabs at the bottom of the code window ( the tabs also could be at the top or sides ) that say XAML and Design, and click the Design tab.

[image]